# Attachment sent with PHPMailer displayed behind HTML content

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm sending mails with phpmailer 6.0.7. The received mail is presented like this:

[Presentation in iOS Mail-App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw3BB.jpg)

I expected to have the attachment at the bottom of the mail content. Is there something I have to consider in my code. My code looks like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom($user->get_mail(), utf8_decode($user->get_vorname()." ".$user->get_nachname()));
$mail->AddAddress($sr->get_mail(), utf8_decode($sr->get_vorname()." ".$sr->get_name()));
$mail->addReplyTo($user->get_mail(), $user->get_vorname()." ".$user->get_nachname());
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $betreff;
$mail->Body = getMailHTML(str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $mailBody), $foot);
$mail->addAttachment($file);
$mail->send();
```

**EDIT**
Here my HTML-Body:

```
function getMailHTML($body, $foot){

    $output = "<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
                            <title>SR-Ausschuss Online</title>
                            <style>
                            @font-face { font-family: \"Source Sans Pro\"; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: local(\"Source Sans Pro Regular\"), local(\"SourceSansPro-Regular\"), url(\"https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/6xK3dSBYKcSV-LCoeQqfX1RYOo3qOK7l.woff2\") format(\"woff2\"); unicode-range: U+0-FF, U+131, U+152-153, U+2BB-2BC, U+2C6, U+2DA, U+2DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD; }
                            @font-face { font-family: \"Source Sans Pro Light\"; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; src: local(\"Source Sans Pro Light\"), local(\"SourceSansPro-Light\"), url(\"https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/6xKydSBYKcSV-LCoeQqfX1RYOo3ik4zwlxdu.woff2\") format(\"woff2\"); unicode-range: U+0-FF, U+131, U+152-153, U+2BB-2BC, U+2C6, U+2DA, U+2DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD; }
                            @font-face { font-family: \"Source Sans Pro Bold\"; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; src: local(\"Source Sans Pro Bold\"), local(\"SourceSansPro-Bold\"), url(\"https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/6xKydSBYKcSV-LCoeQqfX1RYOo3ig4vwlxdu.woff2\") format(\"woff2\"); unicode-range: U+0-FF, U+131, U+152-153, U+2BB-2BC, U+2C6, U+2DA, U+2DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD; }
                            .head{
                                position: absolute; 
                                left: 0px; 
                                top: 60px; 
                                height: 50px; 
                                width: 100%; 
                                font-size: 35px;
                            }
                            .heading{
                                position: absolute; 
                                left: 10px; 
                                top: 0px; 
                                line-height: 50px; 
                                font-size: 35px; 
                                color: #333;
                                font-family: 'Source Sans Pro Light';
                            }

                            .heading b{
                                font-family: 'Source Sans Pro Bold';
                            }

                            .container{
                                float: left;
                                position: absolute;
                                top: 120px;
                                left: 0px;
                                margin: 10px;
                                background-color: #fff;
                                padding: 20px;
                                width: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px);
                                width: -moz-calc(100% - 60px);
                                width: calc(100% - 60px);
                            }

                            .body{
                                width: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
                                width: -moz-calc(100% - 30px);
                                width: calc(100% - 30px);
                                font-family: 'Source Sans Pro','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
                                font-weight: 400; 
                                font-size: 14px; 
                                margin-left: 10px;
                                margin-right: 10px;
                                margin-top: 10px;
                                margin-bottom: 10px;
                                float: both;
                                min-height: 20px;
                            }

                            a.button{
                                float: both;
                                display: block;
                                text-decoration: none;
                                width: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
                                width: -moz-calc(100% - 30px);
                                width: calc(100% - 30px);
                                margin-right: 10px;
                                margin-top: 10px;
                                margin-bottom: 10px;
                                background-color: #00a65a; 
                                color: #fff;
                                text-align: center;
                                height: 40px;
                                line-height: 40px;
                                font-weight: 600;
                            }

                            .foot{
                                font-weight: 400; 
                                font-size: 14px; 
                                margin-left: 10px; 
                                margin: 10px;
                                float: both;
                                min-height: 20px;
                                width: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
                                width: -moz-calc(100% - 30px);
                                width: calc(100% - 30px);
                            }

                            body{
                                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
                                -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; 
                                font-family: 'Source Sans Pro','Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
                                background-color: #d2d6de;
                            }
                            </style>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <div class=\"head\">
                                <span class=\"heading\"><b>SR-Ausschuss</b>Online</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class=\"container\">
                                <div class=\"body\">".$body."</div>
                                <div class=\"foot\">".$foot."</div>
                            </div>
                        </body></html>";

    return $output;
}
```

Body and foot are simple text variables without any own html tags or something. There are only a few line breaks in it. Is it possble to give the attachment a fixed position in mail body?

Comment: Can you paste $mailBody here? I would like to take a look at styling.

Comment: please mention html content

Comment: _“I expected to have the attachment at the bottom of the mail content.”_ - well technically, it is a completely different _part_ of the email, than the HTML content. This is just Gmail’s way of _displaying_ the fact that the mail had an attachment. The HTML content of your mail, or rather its styling, seem to have messed things up here somehow - maybe absolute positioning, negative margins, something like that, that interrupts the normal layout flow somehow, so that this element that is supposed to come below the mail content, slides up instead …

Comment: You have no control over how attachments are displayed, except by using embedded images and references in your HTML. Your CSS is largely pointless as many of the things you are doing will not work in many clients. Keep it simple.